# Gradle version 2.2 is required. Current version is 1.6

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I have tried everything to update gradle in Android 1.5.1 under windows 10, but nothing worked... it keeps saying Gradle version 2.2 is required. Current version is 1.6.

Appreciate any input

Thanks

Comment: "I have tried everything" - what exactly?

Comment: Post the build.gradle in your root folder.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti it is in root folder http://snag.gy/LPq8C.jpg

Answer (score 1):

In your project folder, navigate to you gradle.properties file inside gradle > wrapper folder. Change the version to the lastest 2.12 and resync your project.

`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.12-all.zip`

Comment: Hi, thanks. I have tried this though.. it is not working !

Comment: @androidebug Is your project configured to use the gradle wrapper?

Comment: yes. distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.12-all.zip

Comment: Why do you set it to 2.12 when it need 2.2?

Comment: @androidebug Just import the project again.

Comment: @tinysunlight because you should always use the latest. It's just telling you that the minimum version required is 2.2

Comment: yes. it is set to "default gradle wrapper" under settings

Comment: In your build.gradle file, what is the version of your gradle plugin? It has to be something like `com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.1` at least

Comment: @androidebug File|New|import Project.You should import project again.

Comment: gradle plugin version is set to 1.5.0 , if i try to change it to 1.5.1 and sync it throws error

Comment: Error:Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.1.
Searched in the following locations:
    file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/1.5.1/gradle-1.5.1.pom
    file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/1.5.1/gradle-1.5.1.jar
    https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/1.5.1/gradle-1.5.1.pom
    https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/1.5.1/gradle-1.5.1.jar
Required by:
    :mynewapp:unspecified

Comment: Anyways, 1.5.0 should work. Maybe your have more then one gradle.properties file, try to find all of them.

Comment: @Androiderson only one gradle-wrapper.properties file under /gradle/wrapper

Comment: Of course, I mean your whole workspace. If the error says that the current version is 1.6 it's because of have it set somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio has a setting for ignoring the gradle version in the project and using a local distribution instead.

Under "Preferences" (or "Settings" on Windows) search for "Gradle" and select "Use default gradle wrapper" instead of "Use local gradle distribution.

[image: Screen shot for changing Gradle settings]

Answer (score -1):

Change to

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2-all.zip
```

Then File|New|import Project

Comment: ' D:\mynewapp\app>gradlew assembleRelease FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. * Where: Build file 'D:\mynewapp\app\build.gradle' line: 1 * What went wrong: A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'. > Gradle version 2.2 is required. Current version is 1.6. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in D:\mynewapp\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-2.2-all.zip * Try:Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. BUILD FAILED Total time: 26.301 secs '

Comment: @androidebug can you provide a screenshot of you Project Structure and  gradle.properties?

Comment: Change to 2.2 please and restart Android Studio.